# I need to install libcrypto.so.1.0.0, but I can't figure out how to install it - and apt can't find it

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to install [linuxtrack](https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack) on Ubuntu 22.04.2. After unpacking to /opt, I run

```
$ ldd * | grep 'not found' | sort -u
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
libcwiid.so.1 => not found
liblo.so.7 => not found
libQtCore.so.4 => not found
libQtGui.so.4 => not found
libQtNetwork.so.4 => not found
libQtOpenGL.so.4 => not found
libQtWebKit.so.4 => not found
```

So I need to install *a lot* of stuff. And even the first one is causing me a headache.

I've installed libssl-dev - that didn't solve the problem.

Then I tried this:

```
$ sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.0.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libssl-dev:i386

E: Version '1.0.0' for 'libssl-dev' was not found
```

Then I tried this:

```
$ apt-file search libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

-which returns no output, so it looks like no packages contain that file. Great.

I really don't know what to do now. And this is just the first of eight dependencies, I need to install...

Comment: Since you have tagged with Ubuntu, I am assuming you are running some Ubuntu version, right? If so, which one?

Comment: Also, did you run `configure` and then `make` to compile? Are you sure you need these specific versions? What does `apt-cache search libcrypto` return on your system?

Comment: @terdon Sorry, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I didn't compile this locally, but downloaded from https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack/wiki/Downloads, and then I followed the instructions on https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack/wiki/universal-Linuxtrack-package

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your question and show the output of `apt-cache search libcrypto`. It looks like the specific version isn't available (it is really quite old), but several packages provide a newer one: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcrypto.so&mode=filename&suite=jammy&arch=any. Try installing `libssl-dev` without specifying a version. It is quite possible that the requirement is for `libssl >= 1.0.0` and not for the specific version itself. So if you install a newer one and compile, that might work fine.

Comment: @terdon unfortunately that doesn’t work, `libcrypto` and `libssl` have very restrictive sonames becaude their ABIs changed significantly even in “minor” version bumps.

Comment: You should build it from source by your own. Install for this the necessary -dev packages. The provided binaries are not really universal but specific to some distribution versions.